# How to create tab content at ionic cordova?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, visual-studio-2015, tabs

Currently, i have these codes for ionic tab content. What I'm trying to achieve is to create (2) tabs. I managed to create these 2 tabs, however these codes dont seem to work. I have no idea why whenever i click "tab 2 content (tab)" when the tab is at "tab 1 content"(by default), it will lead me to another page(HomePage.html) instead of showing the intended content(which is at the same page), vice versa. One of the possible reason i could think of, will there be any crash if my Sidemenu.html is declared is such a way. (Although i have no evident in saying that there is crash between Sidemenu.html and TabContent.html)

TabContent.html

```
   <ion-view view-title="Tabs">
        <ion-pane>
            <ion-tabs class="tabs-top">

                <!-- Tab 1 -->
                <ion-tab title="Tab 1" href="#/tab/tab1">
                    <ion-nav-view name="tab-tab1">
                        <ion-content>
                            Tab 1 content
                        </ion-content>

                    </ion-nav-view>
                </ion-tab>


                <!-- Tab 2 -->
                <ion-tab title="Tab 1" href="#/tab/tab2">
                    <ion-nav-view name="tab-tab2">
                        <ion-content>
                            Tab 2 content
                        </ion-content>
                    </ion-nav-view>
                </ion-tab>
            </ion-tabs>

        </ion-pane>
    </ion-view>
```

SideMenu.html

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
          Login
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
          QR Code
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/browse">
          User Profile
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
          Setting
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
          E-Receipt
         </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/BitCoin"  ng-click="clickerBit(item);"  ng-mouseenter="searching();">
         BitCoin     
         </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/Membership">
     membership
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/Redeemption" ng-click="clicker(item);">
            redeemption
          </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

HomePage.html

```
 <ion-view view-title="Home">
        <ion-content>



     <h2>Welcome, " "</h2>

            <img class="homeImg" src="../img/qr.png" width="100" height="100" >
            <br />
            <img class="homeImg" src="../img/profile.png" width="100" height="100">
            <br />
            <img class="homeImg" src="../img/ereceipt.png" width="120" height="120">
            <br />

            <img class="homeImg" src="../img/settings.png" width="100" height="100">
            <input id="target" type="button" value="Insert Data" onclick="AddValueToDB()" />
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>



            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/BitCoin.js"></script>




        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-tab title="Tab 1" href="#/tab/tab2">
```

the href property is what's creating your troubles. If you click on tab, your application will try to go to '#/tab/tab2' and since, I guess, you don't have any state with that url, ui router is redirecting you to default url which must be your homePage.

So maybe remove the href attribute or create a state with #/tab/tab2 and the html of your content (which is a good practive).

Comment: sorry, may i know how can i create a state ?

Comment: you have to use $stateProvider see http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/ and this, since ionic is using ui-router https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ui%20router%20tutorial